# Access variable from inner class without making it final

Tags: java, android, variables, inner-classes, final

how could i get this to work:

```
public void onStart()
        {
            super.onStart();

            int dayN = 0;
            int i = 0;
            String day = null;
            String addFach;

            String mo1 = null;
            String mo2 = null;
            String mo3 = null;
            String mo4 = null;
            String mo5 = null;
            String mo6 = null;
            String mo7 = null;
            String mo8 = null;
            String mo9 = null;
            String mo10 = null;
            String mo11 = null;

            String di1 = null;
            String di2 = null;
            String di3 = null;
            String di4 = null;
            String di5 = null;
            String di6 = null;
            String di7 = null;
            String di8 = null;
            String di9 = null;
            String di10 = null;
            String di11 = null;

            String mi1 = null;
            String mi2 = null;
            String mi3 = null;
            String mi4 = null;
            String mi5 = null;
            String mi6 = null;
            String mi7 = null;
            String mi8 = null;
            String mi9 = null;
            String mi10 = null;
            String mi11 = null;

            String do1 = null;
            String do2 = null;
            String do3 = null;
            String do4 = null;
            String do5 = null;
            String do6 = null;
            String do7 = null;
            String do8 = null;
            String do9 = null;
            String do10 = null;
            String do11 = null;

            String fr1 = null;
            String fr2 = null;
            String fr3 = null;
            String fr4 = null;
            String fr5 = null;
            String fr6 = null;
            String fr7 = null;
            String fr8 = null;
            String fr9 = null;
            String fr10 = null;
            String fr11 = null;

            while (dayN <= 4)
            {
                if (dayN == 0)
                {
                    day = "Montag";
                } else if (dayN == 1)
                {
                    day = "Dienstag";
                } else if (dayN == 2)
                {
                    day = "Mittwoch";
                } else if (dayN == 3)
                {
                    day = "Donnerstag";
                } else if (dayN == 4)
                {
                    day = "Freitag";
                }

                while (i <= 10)
                {

                    BufferedReader buf;
                    try
                    {
                        buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/" + i + day + "fach.txt"));
                        addFach = buf.readLine();

                        if (day == "Montag")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) mo1 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 1) mo2 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 2) mo3 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 3) mo4 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 4) mo5 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 5) mo6 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 6) mo7 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 7) mo8 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 8) mo9 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 9) mo10 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 10) mo11 = addFach;
                        } else if (day == "Dienstag")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) di1 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 1) di2 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 2) di3 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 3) di4 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 4) di5 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 5) di6 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 6) di7 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 7) di8 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 8) di9 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 9) di10 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 10) di11 = addFach;
                        } else if (day == "Mittwoch")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) mi1 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 1) mi2 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 2) mi3 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 3) mi4 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 4) mi5 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 5) mi6 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 6) mi7 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 7) mi8 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 8) mi9 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 9) mi10 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 10) mi11 = addFach;
                        } else if (day == "Donnerstag")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) do1 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 1) do2 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 2) do3 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 3) do4 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 4) do5 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 5) do6 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 6) do7 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 7) do8 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 8) do9 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 9) do10 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 10) do11 = addFach;
                        } else if (day == "Freitag")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) fr1 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 1) fr2 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 2) fr3 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 3) fr4 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 4) fr5 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 5) fr6 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 6) fr7 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 7) fr8 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 8) fr9 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 9) fr10 = addFach;
                            else if (i == 10) fr11 = addFach;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }

                    i++;
                }

                i = 0;
                dayN++;
            }

            RadioButton rB1 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde1);
            RadioButton rB2 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde2);
            RadioButton rB3 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde3);
            RadioButton rB4 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde4);
            RadioButton rB5 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde5);
            RadioButton rB6 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde6);
            RadioButton rB7 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde7);
            RadioButton rB8 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde8);
            RadioButton rB9 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde9);
            RadioButton rB10 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde10);
            RadioButton rB11 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.stunde11);
            DatePicker dP = (DatePicker) getView().findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

            dP.init(dP.getYear(), dP.getMonth(), dP.getDayOfMonth(), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener()
            {
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                    switch(dayOfWeek)
                    {
                        case Calendar.MONDAY:
                            rB1.setText(mo1);
                            break;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

it should set the text of some radiobuttons depending on the weekday of the chosen date with the datepicker.
i cant set the strings final because they get assigned with a value 2 times.

Comment: Use a hashtable. That code is horrible to begin with.

Comment: Please learn about arrays and collections!

Comment: i think this is what u need..[Lesson: Java Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Comment: im only 16, total beginner in java, i need this app as fast as possible. its for personal use only and i dont need better readability or performance. so why should i waste time in using arrays and collections, when i could use copy and paste instead? i know its not a good way to code but its absolutely enough for my purpose

Comment: No Nathan Maier, learning the basic building blocks of modern programming is not a waste of time. Collections exist in order to manipulate data sets in the type of situation you describe. They are in the core libraries of every modern language because all but the most trivial of applications use them. The programming community has developed and refined the standard algorithms for 16*5 years. As a group we are lazy. We have many excellent ways to avoid repeating ourselves. We use pre-built libraries.  We don't do this! This code is terrible! Ignore the advice of the professionals at your peril.

Comment: @SinthiaV that's right but you have to understand that as a beginner you don't want to only read tutorials, reference docs and book all the time. at some point you want to see working results and after that you start reading the next chapter. i have to books about programming (one for Android and one for C++) that together have nearly 1000 pages and on none of these pages stands the word collection.

Comment: @SinthiaV Then you are definitely need to read different books. Learning about collections is an important part of understanding programming. I definitely would not start with C++, way too complicated for a first language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare them as member variables (outside of a method and preferably before `onCreate()` for readibility) they will be accessible throughout the `Activity` even to inner classes of the `Activity`

Comment: Just be aware that declaring them as (mutable) member variables has the drawback of making your method not reentrant (~ aka threadsafe).

Comment: Yes they have become reentrant.How can i get rid of this behavour

Answer (score 4):

No,Not possible.

[JLS # chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.

As a side note:Make use of `Collections` instead of declaring that many fields.

Here is how can you access them example from docs:

```
class WithDeepNesting {
    boolean toBe;
    WithDeepNesting(boolean b) { toBe = b; }

    class Nested {
        boolean theQuestion;
        class DeeplyNested {
            DeeplyNested(){
                theQuestion = toBe || !toBe;  // here you are able to access now.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have used `used but not declared` in both the cases, can you please clarify

Comment: @NathanMaier  If you see the docs,Further they added one example  that how they can be accessed.I posted here that.Yes  I would do this before :).

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to convert them into member variables. However, in your case, you need to rethink your design.

You have way too much code duplication. You should refactor it to use a collection, at which point the inner class problem solves itself.